# Given $2 \times 2$ matrix A over field $F_p$. How many matrices of fixed determinant there exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, prime-numbers, determinant

Note: $p$ is prime number

The idea that I had in mind was to fix the determinant $\Delta$. We can easily say what is determinant of matrix $2 \times 2$. If we put $A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$, then $\Delta = a \cdot d - b \cdot c$. So, if $\Delta$ is fixed then we can write something like this: $$a = \frac{\Delta + b \cdot c}{d}$$

So, for any fixed $b$, $c$ and $d \not= 0$ we are able to easily calculate determinant. But it doesn't seem so trivial how number of ways to set $b, c$ and $d$ can be calculated.

All help and hints will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the determinant 0 matrices separately.

For the others, notice that the map $A \mapsto \det{A}$ is a group homomorphism from $\mathrm{GL}(2,p) \to \mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$, so the set of matrices of determinant $a$ is a coset of the kernel (which is the subgroup of matrices with determinant 1). In other words, for each $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$, there are the same number of matrices with determinant $a$.

Comment: Hm, at first it seemed more obvious. But could you, please, clarify why everything aforementioned follows that number of matrices with determinant $a$ is the same for all $a \in \mathbb{F}^{*}_p$

Comment: The only thing I can see here is Lagrange’s theorem. But if it is so, can you please explain why it helps here

Comment: @math-traveler If you define a map $\phi : \mathrm{GL}(2,p) \to \mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$ by $A \mapsto \det{A}$, this is a surjective homomorphism since $\det{(AB)} = \det{A}\det{B}$. The kernel of this map is the subgroup $\mathrm{SL}(2,p) = \{A : \det{A} = 1\}$ (since 1 is the identity of $\mathbb{F}^{*}$ as a multiplicative group). Then for any $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$, the set of elements with determinant $A$ is a coset of $\mathrm{SL}(2,p)$ and so has the same size as $\mathrm{SL}(2,p)$. Therefore, we have the same number of matrices with determinant $a$ for each $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}$.

Comment: (The cosets of a subgroup all have the same size and partition the elements of the group). I leave out showing that the homomorphism is surjective, you do need to prove that for each $a$ there is at least one matrix $A$ with $\det{A} = a$.

Comment: Thank you for explanation!